# React cannot render font awesome icon

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, react-bootstrap, font-awesome-5, bootswatch

I was using font awesome cart icon in my project. But for some reason the icon is not being rendered in my environment.

This is my **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-YWzhKL2whUzgiheMoBFwW8CKV4qpHQAEuvilg9FAn5VJUDwKZZxkJNuGM4XkWuk94WCrrwslk8yWNGmY1EduTA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <title>ProShop</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the **header.js** file where I am using it in the Nav.link currently, none of user or shopping cart icon is being rendered.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Navbar, Nav, Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap'

function Header() {
    return (
        <header>
            <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" expand="lg" collapseOnSelect>
                <Container>
                    <Navbar.Brand href="/">ProShop</Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                    <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                        <Nav className="mr-auto">
                        <Nav.Link href="/cart"><i className="fas fa-shopping-cart">Cart</i></Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="/login"><i className="fas fa-user">Login</i></Nav.Link>
                        
                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Container>
            </Navbar>
        </header>
    )
}

export default Header
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you should import fontawesome into your project using one of those methods https://fontawesome.com/start

I personally prefer webfonts https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself

It is quite easy to import it

- Just download the archive
- export the content into your project (`/src` folder)
- import `all.min.css` into your `App.js`
- enjoy

Comment: Previously I used to use the CDN version of font-swesome only and it used to work fine, but don't know why its not working, Sunil's answer worked for me but I don't understand why do I need to remove integrity?

Comment: Well, I've never used `<link />` to import something into React so can't say why it isn't working, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

There is a typo in the class name `className="fas fa-user"` it should be `className="fa fa-user"`.

Comment: Nope, its correct. Please check docs